# Retrieve the id last record insert NSManagedObjectID

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have the following code:

```
                ...
                item.id_message = i.id_message;
                item.ref_id = i.ref_id;
                item.datetime_creation = i.datetime_creation;
                [self saveContextAndWait];

                NSManagedObjectID  *moid = [item objectID];
```

how do I retrieve the id of newly inserted record ?

Comment: Which ID? `id_message`, `ref_id` or the `NSManagedObjectID`?

Comment: item is the object that I'm saving.

Comment: "Retrieve the id". And ID is a field that identifies a record. It is not the record itself. Which id? Or do you want to start with just `moid` and go back to having `item`? i.e. to look up item by `moid`?

Comment: How do you insert item?